# JQuery add class to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to set a class name on a (li) element.
This script find all the (a) elements in the list, and creates a click event.

```
jQuery("#" + ElementID).find(TagName).click(function () {

    GetPageByUrl(jQuery(this).attr("href"));
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('yourClass');
    //ChangeSelectedMenuItem(this);
    return false;
});
```

The parent of every (a) element is a (li) element

But nothing happens when this line is executing
jQuery(this).parent().addClass('yourClass');

Everything else is working just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Okay, but it still won't work. It won't add any class jQuery(this).addClass('yourClass'); Should add a class to the (a) element, but it doesn't?

Comment: The posted answers *should* work. To see why they're not working, we need to see the html you're using. And the rest of the relevant jQuery/JavaScript. Could you post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 62):

Specify the optional selector to target what you want:

```
jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('yourClass');
```

Or:

```
jQuery(this).parents('li').addClass('yourClass');
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$(this.parentNode).addClass('newClass');
```

Comment: In a way this comment is both correct and incorrect. It's dependent on your system. If you need to dynamically add a class then the use of jQuery is fine. If you are using this method to add the class instead of modifying the base html then it's not the right way to go.