# Add class to parent span element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to change the class of a checkbox parent element (span) to checked. I'm following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482543/jquery-add-class-to-parent-element) but am getting the error:

$checkbox.parentNode.addClass is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.

Here is the [website](http://35.237.132.231/add-car/)

Here is the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("generateVin").addEventListener("click", function(){

                var $checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")[1];
                var $span=$checkbox.closest("span");
                $checkbox.parentNode.addClass("checked");

});
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing jQuery with vanilla JavaScript. `.addClass()` is a *jQuery* method, meaning it can only be called on *jQuery* elements.

`$checkbox.parentNode` is *not* a jQuery element, but rather a standard JS element.

If you're committed to using jQuery, then it's highly suggested that you go "all the way", rather than going back and forth. The code would look more like this:

```js
$("#generateVin").on("click", function() {
    var $checkbox = $("input[type=checkbox]").eq(1);
    var $span = $checkox.closest("span");    //This doesn't seem to be needed
    $checkbox.parent().addClass("checked");
});
```

- Used jQuery selector syntax to target `generateVin`: `$("#generateVin")`
- Used jQuery event handlers: `.on("click", function() { ... })`
- Converted `$checkbox` to a jQuery element by using jQuery selector and [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/): `var $checkbox = $("input[type=checkbox]").eq(1);`
- Used jQuery's [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) in place of `parentNode`